# Applying kvantum themes to Gtk applications

Tags: kde, themes, gtk, theme-development

Is there any way to apply [Kvantum](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum/tree/master/Kvantum) themes to Gtk applications in Kubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Kvantum is only for Qt applications.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhTFErhE7uA

Comment: @DKBose I've already seen that.But I want the other way around.Making Gtk apps conformant to Kvantum not vice versa.But for now as "@Logix" mentioned it seems impossible.Thanks.